# Vaadin Elements Angular2, won't work with webcomponents-lite.js but works with webcomponents.js

Tags: angular, polymer, vaadin, web-component

All of the documentation for Vaadin Elements seems to suggest webcomponents-lite.js is the only polyfill required to integrate into an Angular2 app on a browser without native support. The issue I am having is that unless I include the full version, Angular complains about the components not being registered in Firefox, IE, and Edge. Everything works fine in Chrome.

If I switch to the full version, the Vaadin Elements work, but there are other issues being caused by including the full polyfill.

Can anyone verify whether or not I should need the full webcomponents polyfill to run Vaadin Element in Firefox, IE, Chrome?

Comment: now with version 1 there's only the webcomponents-lite.js polyfill. did you test it?

Comment: I'm uncertain as to "exactly" what problem you are having,  or how to reproduce it.  Can you add some more details ?

Comment: @petey the problem is that the vaadin split panel doesn't work without the full webcomponentjs polyfill. The resizer bar goes to the left and doesn't move. When I include the full polyfill other features on my site stop working so that isn't an option. All  of the examples show it working with the lite version, so I was just wondering why mine doesn't work without the full version.

Comment: perhaps this will help?
https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/